# Text email/mime parser

Tags: haskell

Does anyone know a good email parser library? Searching Google did not help much.

I have emails dropped locally in maildir format (one mail per file). I need to parse the file extracting body and from parts and save it in a database.

If there is no such thing I could try and write something myself learning on the way.
Any advice on how to start would be appreciated. Do I need to learn parsec or is it easy to do without?

Comment: There seems to be an abandon project on hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HackMail, maybe you could use that as a starting point. (http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HackMail/0.0.1/doc/html/src/HackMail-Data-ParseEmail.html#parseEmailFromFile)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using, say, regular expressions. However, learning to write a parser using `parsec` (or `attoparsec`) is worth the effort, and this seems like a nice, straightforward example to start with. The next time you need to parse something, you will be glad you did. Parsers you write for `parsec` will work with `attoparsec`, and vice versa, as I recall, so it doesn't much matter which you choose. It may be a bit easier to start with `parsec`, because it automatically reports the location of an error.

I learned Parsec from the [documentation](http://gacy.cs.uu.nl/daan/parsec.html). Don't be initimidated by the length of the documentation; you probably won't need to read past page 12 for this task.

Comment: Bear up, parsec is a cool thing, but at the beginning it seems frightening, though if you learned it you will be get tool more powerful than regular expressions

Comment: @mhwombat: the link of the documentation is not working for me. But this works: http://legacy.cs.uu.nl/daan/parsec.html. 
I would also suggest reading chapter 16 of Real World Haskell. Here is the link for the online version: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html